# copying data between different types of containers

Tags: c++11, boost, boost-tuples

I am trying to copy data from one container type to another container type, the containers are both double dimensional vectors, i am using boost::combine and boost::tie to iterate over the containers, the code builds fine but throws a bad_alloc when run. i am not able to understand why a simple code like below throw bad_alloc, what am i doing wrong ?? also what are the other strategies to copy data between containers when they are multi-dimensional.

```
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/container/small_vector.hpp>
#include <boost/range/combine.hpp>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tuple>

int
main(int ac, char **av)
{
    std::vector<std::vector<int>> bv(1, std::vector<int>(4, 99));
    boost::container::small_vector<boost::container::small_vector<int, 4>, 1> bvv;
    decltype(bv)::value_type v1;
    decltype(bvv)::value_type v2;
    BOOST_FOREACH(boost::tie(v1, v2), boost::combine(bv, bvv)){
        for ( auto &e : v1 )
            v2.push_back( e );
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost::combine` expects the passed arguments have the same size. In your case `bv` has 1 `vector<int>` but `bvv` has 0 elements of `boost::container::small_vector` type. And for this reason program crashed. You can add `1` to constructor of `small_vector`

```
boost::container::small_vector<boost::container::small_vector<int, 4>, 1> bvv(1);
```

then program works, but it doesn't do what you expected. `v2` vector is created as new local variable in main function and it is filled by elements of first vector from `bv` container. I think you want to fill `bvv` vector by elements from `bv` container.

If you want to modify `bvv` vector you should pass it as parameter to `boost::tie` function.

```
    BOOST_FOREACH(boost::tie(bv[0], bvv[0]), boost::combine(bv, bvv)){
       std::copy (bv[0].begin(), bv[0].end(), std::back_inserter(bvv[0]));
    }
```

but it only works if `bvv` and `bv` have one element.

Maybe you should not use `boost::combine` and just write loop to iterate over all elements in `bv` and add them to `bvv` container.

```
    for (const auto& v : bv)
    {
        bvv.push_back(boost::container::small_vector<int, 4>());
        std::copy (v.begin(), v.end(), std::back_inserter(bvv.back()));
    }
```

Comment: But i was using boost::small_vector which is supposed to preallocate and pre-reserve the size ???

Comment: `small_vector<T, N, Allocator>` N means preallocated elements, but without calling `push_back`, `resize` etc method it still has 0 elements. `N` is used to allocate memory for elements then while using `push_back` may be faster, but you need to add element explicitly way.